# Preventing an app from being pirated during closed tests

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I want to start using the android closed test from the google play console but am worried that the apk might get leaked to external sites during this phase.

Is there a way of detecting if the users are actually part of the closed test?

Note that when the app is finally released (will be free), I'm fine with the apk being distributed on third party sites since the google play inapp purchase still works.

Comment: What exactly do you call "closed tests"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put [Google Play LVL (License verification Library)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/) into the app. This will ensure the user has acquired the app from Google Play. You can always remove it when you come to finally release your app.